# mixed types of variables in R

Tags: r

I am a new user of R. I have this kind of data type. How can I separate the different types of variables (eg.binary, or counts; or others are continuous) from them?

```
V1    V2  V3  V4  V5   V6  V7  V8  V9       V10     V11    V12
0.17  0   0   12  22   2   1   1   240.215  65.049  1.478  114
0.15  1   0   13  22   2   1   1   247.133  66.315  1.474  120
0.16  0   0   12  22   2   0   1   233.329  58.163  1.353  110
0.07  0   0   12  20   2   0   1   219.660  56.162  1.370  114
0.11  0   0   12  26   2   0   2   289.294  70.844  1.389  134
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is very unclear; please describe exactly what your givens are, what you need to obtain, and what you’ve tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `typeof` to determine the storage mode of an object.

An example data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = 1:2,
                  b = c(0.5, -1.3),
                  c = c("a", "b"),
                  d = c(TRUE, FALSE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

With `lapply` you can apply the function to all columns:

```
lapply(dat, typeof)
```

The result:

```
$a
[1] "integer"

$b
[1] "double"

$c
[1] "character"

$d
[1] "logical"
```

If you want to select, for example, all character columns, you can use:

```
dat[sapply(dat, typeof) == "character"] # possibility 1
dat[sapply(dat, is.character)]          # possibility 2
# both commands will return the same result

  c
1 a
2 b
```

PS: You should also have a look at the functions `mode`and `storage.mode`.

Comment: How would you select or extract all of the character columns from dat?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein the answer is a little bit different from what I want. I'd like to know which of them are binary or counts or continuous etc..

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Sorry, it didn't work for me. It says integer, double etc.. but it can't say the types of variables that I want because all of my data are numerical.

Comment: @user2459558 Both integer and double values are numeric values. Inherently, continuous variables are stored as double. Counts are most likely integers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `typeof`, `str` and `summary` are other possibilities. These can also be applied directly to the data frame, ie no `lapply` or looping required.